# Download manager with browser integration in chrome

Tags: internet

I just want the closest experience to how Internet Download Manager used to work in Windows. IDM seemed to do things in a good way so I just want to have that comfort. Also, internet speeds are so so so slow with Ubuntu compared to Windows. How do I fix that ? I tried disabling ipv6. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get used to the terminal. Run the following commands to install ari2.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aria2
```

Now, when you want to download something, just use the command `aria2c`. Here's an example:

```
aria2c "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Philaethria_hecale_2_Richard_Bartz.jpg"
```

aria2 will resume failed downloads and makes multiple connections to the server to speed things up. You can specify how many connections to make. Here's an example of using 8 connections to the server to do the download faster:

```
aria2c -x8 "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Philaethria_hecale_2_Richard_Bartz.jpg"
```

All files will be downloaded to the current directory. To download to the downloads directory, use the `cd` command to change to that directory before you do the download like in this example:

```
cd ~/Downloads
aria2c -x8 "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Philaethria_hecale_2_Richard_Bartz.jpg"
```

To change back to your home directory, just cd with no directory specified:

```
cd
```

Alternatively, you could use the DownThemAll extension for firefox.

For more info, run the following command:

```
man aria2c
```

Comment: is it possible to use queues ?

Comment: @raudbul certainly, use the same download command separated by a semicolon. `aria2c http://example.com; aria2c http://example.com`  or something like that. When you separate commands by a semicolon, the first command runs and when it finishes, the next one runs after that.

Comment: thanks a lot. I am a complete newbie to Linux so using the Terminal is a bit strange. Thanks for thoroughly explaining everything. The speeds also improved with multiple connections.

Comment: @raudbul awesome, don't forget to mark  this as the accepted answer by clicking the icon to the left if it works, thanks! Also, for more info just run the command  `man aria2c`,  there are so many options I haven't even looked into and I believe you can even use it for torrents but I've never done that myself.